# Random Quote Machine, tweet quote

Tags: javascript, twitter, event-handling, dom-events

I am working through [Free Code Camp's "Random Quote Machine"](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-random-quote-machine-project-6e8d10430f4a) and I built a very (emphasis on very) basic model, however I cannot figure out how to take the quotes and tweet them with the way my code is. Do I have to change my current Javascript code to tweet it, or is there a way to send out a tweet with my current code that I don't realize? I know there is a [another question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172377/twitter-share-button-with-random-quote) with a solution, however I did not understand it. Much thanks.

```js
var quotes= [
    'I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake 
    and for nothing else. John Keats', 
    'But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but 
    not defeated. Ernest Hemingway', 
    'When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and 
    hang on. Franklin D. Roosevelt', 
    'Always do what is right. It will gratify half of mankind 
    and astound the other. ― Mark Twain', 
    'Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it 
    is time to pause and reflect. Mark Twain',
    'It is curious that physical courage should be so common in 
    the world, and moral courage so rare.- Mark Twain in Eruption',
    'A man should not be without morals; it is better to have 
    bad morals than none at all.- Mark Twain\'s Notebook',
    'The most permanent lessons in morals are those which come, 
    not of book teaching, but of experience.- A Tramp Abroad',
    'But the fact that he can do wrong proves his moral 
    inferiority to any creatures that cannot.― Mark Twain',
    '\“Wrong does not cease to be wrong because the majority 
    share in it.\” ― Leo Tolstoy',
    '\“Right is right even if no one is doing it; wrong is wrong 
    even if everyone is doing it.\” ― Augustine of Hippo'
]
function nextQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
    document.getElementById("displayQuote").innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
<!--Javascript will go in div-->
<div>
    <h2 id="displayQuote"></h2>
</div>
<button onclick="nextQuote()">New Quote</button>
<button id="tweetQuote"><a>Tweet</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code throws an error like "unterminated string leteral" because you must not have line brakes in your `quotes`-array elements.

After fast clean up - now it works like a charme.

```js
var quotes= [
    'I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else. John Keats', 
    'But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated. Ernest Hemingway', 
    'When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on. Franklin D. Roosevelt', 
    'Always do what is right. It will gratify half of mankind  and astound the other. ― Mark Twain', 
    'Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it is time to pause and reflect. Mark Twain',
    'It is curious that physical courage should be so common in the world, and moral courage so rare.- Mark Twain in Eruption',
    'A man should not be without morals; it is better to have bad morals than none at all.- Mark Twain\'s Notebook',
    'The most permanent lessons in morals are those which come, not of book teaching, but of experience.- A Tramp Abroad',
    'But the fact that he can do wrong proves his moral inferiority to any creatures that cannot.― Mark Twain',
    '\“Wrong does not cease to be wrong because the majority share in it.\” ― Leo Tolstoy',
    '\“Right is right even if no one is doing it; wrong is wrong even if everyone is doing it.\” ― Augustine of Hippo'
]
function nextQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
    document.getElementById("displayQuote").innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    document.getElementById("tweetQuote").href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=" +  quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
<!--Javascript will go in div-->
<div>
    <h2 id="displayQuote"></h2>
</div>
<button onclick="nextQuote()">New Quote</button>
<a href="#" id="tweetQuote"><button>Tweet</button></a>
```

You have to debug you code if something doesn't work...

Comment: I made it so it does not have line breaks, you are right it is significantly faster. Do you know how to tweet the quote from there? I have visited this post ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172377/twitter-share-button-with-random-quote?rq=1  ) but I did not understand what they were doing by adding the addEventListener. (I did visit W3schools) I know this is a beginners question, thanks for your patience

Comment: @JohnSmith please note: there was a bug in my code. now its updatet and alright...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have 15 rep yet, "it is recorded, but not publicly added." When I get 15 I'll be sure to come back and re-hit the up-vote button. Your good deed shall not go unnoticed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome @JohnSmith. Didn't know with the 15 reps (only 7 to go) :)

Answer (score 1):

While my first answer was about fixing the original source code, this one is more like a recommendation on how to implement the functionality in a better way.

```js
// lets start with a "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"
// to not pollute the global namespace
(function() {

    // cache elements that are reused
    var aQuotes = [ 'Quote 1', 'Quote 2', 'Quote 3', 'Quote 4' ],
        iQuotes = aQuotes.length,
        domDisplayQuote = document.getElementById("displayQuote"),
        domTweetQuote = document.getElementById("tweetQuote");

    // listen to "click event" on "button#nextQuote"
    document.getElementById("nextQuote").addEventListener('click', function() {

        var sQuote = aQuotes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * iQuotes ) ];
        // use cached DOMelements
        domDisplayQuote.innerHTML = sQuote;
        domTweetQuote.href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=" + sQuote;

    }), false;

})()
```

```html
<h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
<div>
    <h2 id="displayQuote"></h2>
</div>
<!-- instead of <button onclick="nextQuote()">New Quote</button> -->
<button id="nextQuote">New Quote</button>
<a href="#" id="tweetQuote"><button>Tweet</button></a>
```